# Responsive Design my media queries isn't working?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to turn my website into a responsive site however, my media queries doesn't seem to be working at all. I'm not sure what I have done or why its not working. Any help would be great.

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin: -31px 10px 5px 145px;
}

#left {
     width: 47%;
     float: left;
}

#rightarticle {
width: 48%;
float: right;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
    #logo {
    margin: -31px 10px 5px 145px;
    }

    #left {
       width: 47%;
float: left;
    }

    #rightarticle {
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the original css too? the media query looks properly formatted. It may be something to do with the rest of your css

Comment: added normal css for those elements. I thought I could target certain elements and change the CSS styling in media queries.

Comment: Your media query rules don't modify any styles, because when the final style is computed all applicable rules are combined together (this is what "cascading" means).  If you want to prevent floating behavior, you need to explicitly specify `float:none` in media query rules so they overwrite global rules (`float: left` and `float:right` respectively).